# Add header while connecting to schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, hortonworks-data-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I want to send some custom request headers while connecting to schema registry from my java producer application.

Everytime I connect to the registry using the app, I want to send a header with the app-name so as to authenticate if the app can use the registry or not (I have handled all that with lua scripts in my nginx conf)

Only doubt I have is, how do I send headers with my request while connecting to schema registry from a java application

Im using hortonworks schema registry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just had to use the schema-registry Rest API to connect to the registry and post my schemas etc